# Why is my module not recognized in simple Node.js app? Error: Cannot find module 'fwsp-hydra-express'

Tags: node.js

My code starts with

```
var hydraExpress = require('fwsp-hydra-express');
var config = require('./config.json');
```

This is the error

```
 node index.js
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'fwsp-hydra-express
```

I checked again in node_modules

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 mm mm 4096 Dec 25 09:33 fwsp-hydra-express/
```

package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "fwsp-hydra-express": "^1.0.0"
  }
```

Why is this module not recognized?

Comment: Is this package exists under dependencies in `package.json`? Try to completely remove node_modules and execute `npm install` again.

Comment: I got the same after,rm -rf and new install.

Comment: which node version are u using?

Comment: node v8.10.0, npm 3.5.2

Comment: I think fwsp-hydra-express is outdated. Try and use hydra-express.

Comment: may i know why are u using use npm module?

Comment: For npm install.

Comment: as suggested by @PrateekOraon try using hydra-express